# Infinite Mobile touch slider

Tags: javascript, mobile, slider

I am using https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper and it's smooth and all great but I can't manage the following:

I have an infinite list I would like to have 1-2-3 and start on 2
when i load 3 i will load 4 and unload one same thing in the other direction when on one load 0 then -1 but always have only 3-5 slides loaded as they are full of heavy content.

Here is what i have so far! Very much appreciated!

```
swiper = new Swiper('.swiper1',{   onSlideChangeEnd : function(e) {

   if(e.activeSlide == $('.swiper-slide').length -1){
    swiper.appendSlide("smth");
    swiper.removeSlide(0);
    //swiper.getSlide(2);
  }

  if(e.activeSlide == 0){
   swiper.prependSlide("smth");
   swiper.removeLastSlide();
 }

}
});
```

btw Forward I can get it to work until I swiper.removeSlide(0); backward i can seem to prepend without switching page

Comment: wow, i have no idea what you're trying to achieve here lol

Comment: Simplified it. I think it's going to be tricky for someone to help me :-(

Comment: ye its a little confusing. I think maybe a working example would help a lot.